# What happens if I install a GNU/Linux distro for ARMv7h in an ARMv7l machine?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, arch-arm

I would like to install [Parabola](https://www.parabola.nu/) in a Banana Pi, which is a SBC based in Raspberry pi. It has an ARMv7l processor, and Parabola is for ARMv7h. I read [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166619/differences-between-arm-versions-armv7-only) and as far as I understand, there's should be no problem, right?

Comment: Is it a big deal to just try it?

Comment: No, but I just wanna know

Comment: If the ARMv7h instruction set is a subset of that of the ARMv7l, then it should work.